# How many times will the line be executed on average as a function of n?

Tags: algorithm, permutation, probability

The given algorithm takes an array A of n pairwise distinct numbers as input. A is assumed to be a permutation of the values `1, 2, ..., n`.

```
m = +inf
for i <- 1,...,n do
   if A[i]<m then 
      m <- A[i] (*)
return m
```

On average over all permutations of the input, how many times will `m <- A[i]` be executed?

**My intuition:**

The line will be executed at least once in the first iteration.
In the second iteration the chance is 50%.
In the third iteration the chance is 33.334%
Can it be that in every round i the chance to be executed is 1/i?
And if so why?

Comment: Might be better suited for math.SE

Comment: Just to be explicit, 1-based indexing for `A`?

Answer (score 2):

I came to this result (lmk if you agree):
The chance for the i-th round to execute the line is 1/i.
Because it will be executed if it's the smaller than all the numbers before hand.
Therefore we can take the expected value of all the rounds as the sum of:

\sum_{i=1}^n 1/i = H_n := Harmonic-number of n

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have a bag with n elements 1-n in it, and we draw k.

In how many ways can we draw k so that the first (k-1) elements are in decreasing order, and the k'th is not?

There are (k-1) choices for the last element: anything but the smallest of the elements we're considering. Then, there is one way for the remaining k-1 elements to be drawn, so our count is (k-1).

There are r! orderings of r elements. So the chance of a valid run of length k-1 is (k-1) / k!. This applies for 0 <= k <= n-1.

Note here that k includes the first element not in decreasing order, so is one more than the run length.

```
run_len k   chance                      contrib_to_expectation
1       2   1/2! = 1/2 = 0.5            0.5
2       3   2/3! = 1/3 = 0.333333333    0.6666666
3       4   3/4! = 1/8 = 0.125          0.375
4       5   4/5! = 0.033333333          0.1333333
5       6   5/6! = 0.006944444          0.0347222
```

As seen above, the contributions to expectation are the run length times the chance. Since the chance has a factorial in the denominator, these quickly get quite small. For any nontrivial length, the answer will round to 1.718281828 (starting at a run length of 13).

The edge case that you might care about for small values of n is that the contribution to expectation of k=n is n/n! = 1/(n-1)!

Experimental results I've run are centered around 1.718, as expected.

Comment: That sure looks like `e - 1`

Comment: To be clear, this gives the expected length of the decreasing sequence, which is the expected number of times m <- A[i] will be executed. If you need the counts per length, we could modify this to get that.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct...  although before figuring that out, I arrived at an answer this way:

Assuming a very large `n`, every time `m` is assigned, the number of remaining elements smaller than `m` is multiplied by a uniform random factor in [0,1].  Assignments terminate when there are no smaller numbers remaining.

Equivalently, every time `m` is assigned, the log of this number of remaining smaller numbers is reduced by a random amount, chosen with a fixed non-uniform distribution.  The expected number of assignments required to get below any constant value is therefore in ϴ(log n).

H<sub>n</sub> is in ϴ(log n) as well, and I wrote a little program to test it:

```py
def case(n):
    ret = 0
    while n > 1:
        n = random.randrange(n)
        ret += 1
    ret += n
    return ret

def test(n):
    ret = 0
    for i in range(10000):
        ret += case(n)
    return ret/10000

for i in range(10):
    print(2**i, test(2**i))
```